# How do I clone a schema?

Tags: cockroachdb

Suppose I have an existing schema (s1) with the following tables:
s1.table1
s1.table2

I would like to clone this schema to a new schema (s2) i.e.:
s2.table1
s2.table2

How can I achieve this?
The purpose is for testing without touching the original data.
I'm aware of the EXPORT command but it appears to be able to only export 1 table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a table's definition to a new table, without copying the data in the original table using [`CREATE TABLE ... LIKE`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-table.html#create-a-table-like-an-existing-table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE s2.table1 (LIKE s1.table1 INCLUDING ALL);
CREATE TABLE s2.table2 (LIKE s1.table2 INCLUDING ALL);
```

You can then copy the rows from the original table if needed:

```sql
INSERT INTO s2.table1 SELECT * FROM s1.table1;
INSERT INTO s2.table2 SELECT * FROM s1.table2;
```

Comment: This won't work for me since it is labor intensive and i might miss a table/constraint/key.